# Is iOS & Android Push Notification reliable

Tags: android, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We recently added released new iOS & android mobile application, we tried to send push notification few time over past few days but it doesn't seems to be reliable. Sometimes it works & sometimes it doesn't work for some reason.

Take for example You may received it on latest iPhone 6 & not on iPhone 5 or other-way round. Same could happen in case on Android devices.

Are their any hard and fast runs for sending new Push Notification that should be taken into consideration when sending push notification.

Is their a way we can check if a user has received notification or some way of testing push notification without sending it to actual subscribed users.

How Reliable is Push Notification?

Comment: Please consider https://pushy.me, a paid service I founded with the sole intention of improving notification speed & reliability.

Answer (score 0):

It's a best effort service, push notification delivery is not guaranteed at 100%. Especially if you're running the app in sandbox/testing mode.

As you can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html):

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available.

Also take a look at the Quality of Service section of that document.